# Bootstrap 3.0.0 modal events not firing

Tags: jquery, modal-dialog, twitter-bootstrap-3, bootstrap-modal

I can't seem to get modal events working at all using Bootstrap 3.  I want to perform an action when my modal closes, but nothing's happening.

Here's my stripped back HTML:

```
<button type="button" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#imageUpload">Launch modal</button>

<div class="modal fade" id="imageUpload" tabindex="-1">
<div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
        Upload form here
    </div><!-- /.modal-content -->
</div><!-- /.modal-dialog -->
```

and my JS:

```
$(function(){
    $('#imageUpload').modal({
        show: false
    });

    $('#imageUpload').on('hidden', function () {
        window.alert('hidden event fired!');
    });
});
```

I've put a JSfiddle together here - http://jsfiddle.net/EcnC3/1/

I've not found any other reports of modal events not working in Bootstrap 3 so I'm sure I've done something wrong, but can't figure it out.  Thanks for any help you can offer

Comment: $(window).on('hidden.bs.modal', function (e) {

Answer (score 21, accepted):

According to [documentation](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#modals) the event name is like `shown.bs.modal`:

```
$('#imageUpload').on('shown.bs.modal', function () {
   alert('show event fired!');
});
```

Have a look at this **[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/EcnC3/2/)**

Comment: didn't realize I was looking at the 2.3.2 docs by mistake, thanks!

Answer (score 35):

remove the .fade class from your modal. 
this worked for me.

Comment: This worked for me, as did using 'show.bs.modal' instead of 'shown'

Comment: This worked for me as well. A possible hacky workaround is simply running your code in a setTimeout > 150ms (thats the length of the CSS3 animation for .fade) inside the show.bs.modal trigger. i.e

`$('#imageUpload').on('show.bs.modal', function () {
   setTimeout(function(){
       alert('modal is visible!');
   }, 200);
});`

Comment: Nice find on the fade class. Hard to believe that hasn't been addressed yet.

Comment: are you kidding me???  why isn't this fixed!  confirming that removing .fade from the .modal element fixes the issue when you register a .on(...) handler for a modal that is invoked with options (see OP)

Answer (score 6):

removing the `fade` class on the modal element do the fix.

https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/issues/11793

see @Fint answer

Answer (score 0):

There seems to be a bug in the Bootstrap.min.css file for the modal dialog. I changed it to Bootstrap.css and the dialog is now visible.

Answer (score 0):

The answer marked correct is just that, but an addition to the massive list of 'Dumb things I have done' - also be careful which DOM Element you target. It should be the outer modal Div.

For example if you are using RequireJS and a template manager like Knockout-amd-helper you might have markup like this

Parent markup:

```
<div class="modal fade" id="addThingModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="addThingModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div data-bind="module: { name: 'addThing'}"></div>
</div>
```

Template:

```
<div id="addThingTemplate" class="modal-dialog">
   ...
</div>
```

your script should target '#addThingModal' not '#addThingTemplate'