# how to destroy a session inside a javascript

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, codeigniter, session

I have created a session that stores some data, and this data is displayed in the modal after 2-3 clicks depending on the condition inside a modal. I wish that as soon as this modal is closed the session should get destroyed.

I have created multiple sessions and the one that I am dealing with is the following session

```
$data = array(
  'id' => $row->id,
  'name' => $row->name,
  'email' => $row->email,
  'loggedin' => true
);

$this->session->set_userdata($data);
```

I have the following code to detect that the modal has been closed or not

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   $('#modal_large').on('hidden.bs.modal', function (e) {
    console.log("closed");

  })

</script>
```

Among all the session i wish to destroy only this session for this i am using the following code

```
$this->session->unset_userdata('loggedin');
```

But i don't know how i can unset the session inside javascript

Can anyone please help me with this

Comment: You can use ajax for destroy a session.

Comment: @Dave how can i do that?  and will it detect the modal close part, because i want to destroy session only when modal is closed

Comment: `I don't know how i can unset the session inside javascript` You can't. JS runs on the client and the session is stored on the server. They are two separate entities which cannot directly communicate. To achieve what you need you'll need to send an AJAX request from JS to PHP which then destroys the session value you require

Comment: @sammy : create one function for destroy a session, and call ajax to that function.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [ajax](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.get/) to make a server call when the modal is closed.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   $('#modal_large').on('hidden.bs.modal', function (e) {
    console.log("closed");
    // Add a get request to a server URL to process logout
    $.get( "site/logout", function( data ) { // put your URL instead
      // Route to a login screen or something, the logout is complete
      alert( "Logout complete." );
    });
  })
</script>
```

Then, in a controller at the URL specified, you can call the line you mentioned: `$this->session->unset_userdata('loggedin');`

Comment: it is not detecting that the modal has been closed or not and therefore not URL is not working

Comment: Okay, well that sounds like an entirely different question then, and outsode of the scope of this one. Perhaps take a look here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18568278/bootstrap-3-0-0-modal-events-not-firing?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa